# Error thrown every time i try to run premake

Tags: c++, lua, premake

i wanted to tryout premake5 for a project, but every time i try to run

```
premake5 vs2019
```

it throws:

```
Error: ** Error: Cannot find either vs2005.lua or vs2005.lua.lua or vs2005.lua/premake5.lua or vs2005.lua/premake4.lua
```

I have no idea what the issue could be since i dont know anything about premake.

Here is what I've tried:

1. Recompiling premake5 from source.
2. Tried running the example
   code(https://premake.github.io/docs/Your-First-Script).
3. Googling the error code.

Comment: Fixed is trunk now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trunk version is indeed broken (by me :-/ with that [commit](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/commit/bcbe8ea9d1c9fa3e7d336259eb16e1161f7365e1) the 9th august 2023)

There is already that [PR](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/pull/2122) to fix that issue in trunk.

<strike>Wait for merge which should come soon, or apply it locally</strike> 
Merge is done, so update,
or use tagged version.

Working with trunk version might have those kind of issue.
Using release/tagged version should mitigate that.